# How to point to Html folder from path module Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path

I want to send html file as response using `express` so to do that I need to give the position or `path` of `index.html` file.

so this is my file structure -

```
MyWebsite 
     Html
        index.html
     Css
        index.css
     Js
       index.js
```

if you still not understanding the file structure this the image of file structure :

[image]

so in my JavaScript I have written something like this :

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const app = express();

const port = process.env.port || 8080;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const htmlFile = path.join(__dirname, '/index.html');
  res.sendFile(htmlFile)
});

app.listen(port);
```

giving error -

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'F:\Websites\MyWebsite\js\index.html'
```

It is not working!. I am unable to give the path or folder name! how can I get the `index.html` folder's path

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its simple you have set back-word so server can find you index.html change your code to

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   const htmlFile = path.join(__dirname, '/index.html');
   res.sendFile(htmlFile)
});
```

new Code Will Be

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const htmlFile = path.join(__dirname, '../html/index.html');
  res.sendFile(htmlFile)
});
```

i hope its work for you its  work for me

Comment: thank you it is working but why my css is not loading only html is loading

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'path' module to move one directory back.

```
path.join(__filename, '..', 'html', 'index.html')
```

this way you will avoid slashes and eliminate problems while running your app in different operating systems.

Comment: thank you @JulioBordeaux can you tell me why my html file is only loading not css 

Comment: '..' means that you are going one folder back and 'html' parameter means that you are entering html directory to look for 'index.html' file. If you want to access css folder you can change 'html' to 'css'